# Git best practices on keeping previous versions

Tags: git, version-control, version

I'm currently working on an application which runs a model, and a common request is that we need to compare the current model to previous versions with the same inputs. As of now we keep a copy for each production version so it looks like this:

application_base

- v1
- v2
- v3
- etc

as their own folder, and that entire thing is pushed to the repository. This seems like ... not the best way to do this, and it causes pull requests for each version to make it look like hundreds of files had code changes, even if it was only a couple. I've seen a couple of approaches and all of them seem hacky, I can't be the only one who's ever had this issue, what's the best practice for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You are completely subverting the point of git and version control systems in general by keeping versions in separate folders rather than relying on the commit history. RE your comment below, the different teams can simply check out a tagged version, as simple as `git checkout v2.2.1`. They don't need to be experts on git. You can even give them a GUI front end to Git.

Comment: So is the answer that git (or at least a single repo) shouldn't be used in this use case? This isn't flexible, there needs to be a central location on a shared server where multiple versions of the application exist and then other teams can run against any of those. There's no reality where I convince management to adopt a workflow that requires our customers learning enough git to checkout the version they want before running it, they have pretty limited technical skills. I realize this isn't ideal but that's how it is in the real world sometimes, and I'm trying to find the least bad option.

Comment: Yes, that is my answer. If you version by directory, then why use a version control system? VSC are about maintaining versions *in situ*, tracking changes and allowing you to check out prior versions. If you are using git correctly (making changes *in situ* and using `git commit` and `git checkout`), but only use the "release versions in directories" approach for your customers, then don't use git for that latter part. Use a plain file server. Devs copy or rsync new version to it as needed. See how GitHub allows you to publish "Releases" which are not stored in your git repo. Same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) to mark versions/releases. This way, you can do all the work in one directory. Diff's instead of being huge are gonna be just the differences.

It is also easy to checkout the specific tag so you should be able "to compare the current model to previous versions with the same inputs".

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work, we require multiple versions to be available at the same time. There may be one team running tests on version 1, another on version 2, etc. They also don't generally know how to use git let alone do we trust them to be modifying our application source code (which would be required to let them do the checkouts). Your approach seems to be standard when we just want the old versions available for records and comparisons by our team, but when some consumers may want to access an old version without interacting with our team, that would break down.

Comment: Also reading your response I may not have expressed it well, when I say compare the current model to previous versions I don't mean the source code differences I mean the output, so we would need to run version 1, version 2, version 3, etc. and compare the outputs. Obviously we would also like to be able to compare code as well.

Comment: Based on the info you've provided in upper comments it seems to me that you need to use something like [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/).
This way someone who has access to your artifactory repositories can download previously pre-built models and can run them in their own environment and they can then compare the output.. You can still compare source code differences via git.